# force cp to copy on dangling symlinks

Tags: symbolic-link, cp

Is there any way to force `cp` (Bash 4.2.5, Ubuntu 12.04) to copy onto a dangling symlink?

```
cp a-file path/to/danling/symlink/a-file
cp: not writing through dangling symlink `path/to/danling/symlink/a-file`
```

`cp -f` seems to be impotent in this case and results in the same message.

Comment: Did you try using `cp -f` instead?

Comment: @RohithMadhavan yep; same message (I just updated the question)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Make `cp` remove the target file before copying:

```
$ ln -s /random/file f              
$ cp -f a f                  
cp: not writing through dangling symlink ‘f’
$ cp --remove-destination a f
$ diff a f && echo yes
yes
```

From [`man cp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/cp.1.html):

```
--remove-destination
      remove  each existing destination file before attempting to open
      it (contrast with --force)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `unlink theSymLink` where `theSymLink` is the actual symlink, then try again

Comment: This will work, but note that [`unlink`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/unlink.1.html) has the same effect as (and thus no advantage compared to) the more commonly used [`rm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/rm.1.html). In particular, like `rm foo`, `unlink foo` will delete a file `foo` even when it is a regular file and not a symbolic link. Using `unlink` instead of `rm` (or `mv --remove-destination ...`) does *not* guard against accidental data loss.